# How do you score documents in elastic search based on the sequence of occurrence of tokens

Tags: string, elasticsearch, search, recommendation-engine, opensearch

Lets say you have three documents in elastic search

```
{
  name : "Amalayse, Urine",
}, 
{
  name : "Urine Amalayse"
},
{
  name : "Complete Test For Urine"
}
```

And you searched for "Urin"
I want the second document to rank the highest as the token was found earliest.

Is there way to check how early the token was found

I have tried phrase prefix but it doesn't check for sequence.